# R XgBoost train error "At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name"

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to fit a XgBoost model in R, but when I run it, I get the error :

"At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names".

Here is my code:

```
xgb_grid = expand.grid(
  nrounds =100,
  eta=c(0.3,0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001),
  gamma=c(0,1),
  max_depth=c(2,4,6,8,10),
  min_child_weight=(0:200)*0.1,
  subsample=(0:100)*0.01,
  colsample_bytree=(0:100)*0.01
)

xgb_trcontrol = trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 5,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  returnData = FALSE,
  returnResamp = "all",
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  allowParallel = TRUE
)
caret::train()
xgb_train <- caret::train(
  x = as.matrix(train_n[,predictorsNames]),
  y= as.factor(train_n[,outcomeName]),
  trControl =xgb_trcontrol,
  tunegrid = xgb_grid,
  method = "xgbTree",
  metric = "ROC"
)
```

From what I read, it has to do with the levels of the y factor. But yet again, for Xgboost I recall that all variables have to be numeric, including y. Or am I wrong? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Seems like you're wrong. (a) You *don't* give a numeric `y`, you explicitly convert it to a `factor`. (b) The error you get doesn't say *"you must have a numeric y!"*, rather it says it *"the levels of your factor aren't valid variable names!"*. What you should do is correct the levels of your factor so they are valid variable names. If you need help with that, you should share `levels(as.factor(train_n[,outcomeName]))`.

Comment: Using str("some variable") can help?